# Redux RTK reloading state when calling getSelectors

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am new to Redux RTK so the problem might not exactly be on calling getSelectors(). However, when I'm using the state that comes from getSelectors() it reloads the entire state.

**Problem**
The baseline is that I have different Setup objects that I'm calling based on the documentId. These Setup objects are quite large so in the getSetups I am only fetching some basic properties. Then, when the user selects a specific Setup from the dropdown I want to save it in the setupSlice. But when I trigger the dispatch(setSetup(data)) the RTK reloads all the Setups.
I encounter an infinite loop when after fetching all the Setup objects I want to automatically assign the default Setup to the setupSlice.

**Extra**
Ideally when I assign a Setup to the setupSlice I would like to call the getSetup from RTK to fetch the entire Setup object of that specific Setup and store it in the setupSlice.

I am not sure if this is suppose to be happening but is there anyway to stop it? Otherwise is there any recommendation so I can move forward?

This is the component I'm trying to generate:

```
const SetupDropdown = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { documentId } = useParams()

    const { data, isFetching } = useGetSetupsQuery({ documentId })

    let setupsMenu;
    const { selectAll: selectAllSetups } = getSelectors({documentId})
    const allSetups = useSelector(selectAllSetups)

    if (!isFetching) {
        const defaultSetup = allSetups.find((setup) => setup.default)
        setupsMenu = allSetups.map(setup => {
            return (<MenuItem value={setup.id}>{setup.name}</MenuItem>)
        })
        dispatch(setSetup(defaultSetup))
    }

    

    const setupId = useSelector(selectSetupId)

    const handleChange = async (event) => {
        // Here I ideally call the getSetup RTK Query to fetch the entire information of the single setup
        const data = {
            id: event.target.value,
            name: 'Random name'
        }
        dispatch(setSetup(data))

    };

    return (
        <FormControl sx={{ minWidth: 200 }} size="small">
            <InputLabel>Setup</InputLabel>
            <Select
                value={setupId}
                onChange={handleChange}
                label="Setup"
            >
                {setupsMenu}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
    )
}

export default SetupDropdown;
```

This is the setupApiSlice:

```
const setupsAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
    sortComparer: (a, b) => b.date.localeCompare(a.date)
})

const initialState = setupsAdapter.getInitialState()

export const setupsApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    tagTypes: ['Setup'],
    endpoints: builder => ({
        getSetups: builder.query({
            query: ({ documentId }) => ({
                url: `/documents/${documentId}/setups`,
                method: 'GET'
            }),
            transformResponse: responseData => {
                return setupsAdapter.setAll(initialState, responseData)
            },
            providesTags: (result, error, arg) => [
                { type: 'Setup', id: "LIST" },
                ...result.ids.map(id => ({ type: 'Setup', id }))
            ]
        }),
        getSetup: builder.query({
            query: ({ documentId, setupId }) => ({
                url: `/documents/${documentId}/setups/${setupId}`,
                method: 'GET'
            })
        })
    })
})

export const {
    useGetSetupsQuery,
    useGetSetupQuery
} = setupsApiSlice

// Define function to get selectors based on arguments (query) of getSetups
export const getSelectors = (
    query,
  ) => {
    const selectSetupsResult = setupsApiSlice.endpoints.getSetups.select(query)
  
    const adapterSelectors = createSelector(
      selectSetupsResult,
      (result) => setupsAdapter.getSelectors(() => result?.data ?? initialState)
    )
  
    return {
      selectAll: createSelector(adapterSelectors, (s) =>
        s.selectAll(undefined)
      ),
      selectEntities: createSelector(adapterSelectors, (s) =>
        s.selectEntities(undefined)
      ),
      selectIds: createSelector(adapterSelectors, (s) =>
        s.selectIds(undefined)
      ),
      selectTotal: createSelector(adapterSelectors, (s) =>
        s.selectTotal(undefined)
      ),
      selectById: (id) => createSelector(adapterSelectors, (s) =>
        s.selectById(s, id)
      ),
    }
  }
```

This is the setupSplice:

```
const initialState = {
    name: null,
    filters: [],
    data: {},
    status: 'idle', //'idle' | 'loading' | 'succeeded' | 'failed'
    error: null
}

const setupSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'setup',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setSetup: (state, action) => {
            console.log('Dispatch')

            const setup = action.payload;
            console.log(setup)
            state.id = setup.id;
            state.name = setup.name;
            state.filters = setup.filters;
            state.data = setup.state;
            state.status = 'succeeded';
        }
    }
})

export const { setSetup } = setupSlice.actions;

export const selectSetupId = (state) => state.setup.id;
export const selectSetupName = (state) => state.setup.name;
export const selectSetupFilters = (state) => state.setup.filters;
export const selectSetupData = (state) => state.setup.data;

export default setupSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tbh., you probably should be using `selectFromResult` in your `useGetSetupsQuery` instead of adding another `useSelector` hook. That would also reduce your code complexity by a lot.

Your problem as hand is that you are creating those selectors within your component on each render - so they don't have a chance to actually memoize and give you a stable result. If you do that in your component, wrap it in a `useMemo` call to keep your selector instances as stable as possible.

Comment: So I added the `useMemo` to my component as in `SetupDropdown = React.memo(SetupDropdown)` but it did not solve the issue. Additionally, I believe I have to use an additional useSelector to get the entities (I'm using an adapter for the RTK). Otherwise I get a data object and cannot loop through data.entities with the map function.

Comment: That component will rerender whenever anything related to it changes - the `React.memo` will only prevent rerenders when a parent rerernders and props did not change. You do not need an extra `useSelector`, `selectFromResult` is enough - but you migh need to check if `data` is there at all - `selectFromResult` allows you to select from the full result, not from `data` only; and if `isLoading` is `true`, `result.data` is `undefined` etc.

Comment: Could you provide me with a little more context on how to implement the `selectFromResult`? I am trying to use it like this `const { setup } = useGetSetupsQuery({ documentId }, {
        selectFromResults: ({ data }) => ({
            setup: data ?? [],
        })
    })` but it is not working for me. I tried to remove the `transformeResponse` and only pass it a `provideTags` of `['Setup']` but nothing is working.

Comment: That code should pretty much be working if you just want to get `data` out of the result, call it `setup` and give it a default value. Otherwise, there is an example [here in the Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced#selecting-values-from-results) - does that help?